# Unit testing button click is not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing

I have added a button programmatically and I have to run unit test for automation process. We dont have much UI components so we dont use UI testing bundle.

Added button in code

```
self.proceedButton.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, (buttonContainerWidth * 0.75), (buttonContainerHeight * 0.3));
self.proceedButton.center = CGPointMake(self.buttonContainer.center.x, CGRectGetHeight(self.proceedButton.frame));
self.proceedButton.layer.cornerRadius = CGRectGetHeight(self.proceedButton.frame) / 2;
self.proceedButton.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
self.proceedButton.titleLabel.font = proceedFont;
[self.proceedButton addTarget:self action:@selector(onAcceptClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Test:

```
[vc viewDidLoad];
NSString *selector = [[vc.proceedButton actionsForTarget:vc forControlEvent:UIControlEventTouchUpInside] firstObject];
XCTAssert([selector isEqualToString:@"onAcceptClicked"]);
[vc.proceedButton sendActionsForControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

This fails if I comment out the `[self.proceedButton addTarget:self action:@selector(onAcceptClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];` line so it seems the test is written correctly.

However `sendActionsForControlEvents:` is not entering `onAcceptClicked` method in the test.

Why this is happening? Is it possible that unit test is finishing before `onAcceptClicked` getting actually called?

Answer (score 1):

This could be because you are calling `[vc viewDidLoad]` directly, which [Apple advises you not to do](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/loadView), presumably because a bunch of setup is performed before `viewDidLoad` is eventually invoked.

> You should never call this method directly. The view controller calls this method when its view property is requested but is currently nil. This method loads or creates a view and assigns it to the view property.

Instead, try using `XCTAssertNotNil(vc.view);` at the beginning. This will try to load the view, eventually calling `viewDidLoad` for you and probably setting up your button so that the actions are correctly added to it.

**Edit** So if it helps, I've just quickly run this test and I can verify that the method `onAcceptClicked` is called in the view controller when the test runs.

**Button setup in `viewDidLoad`**

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(50, 40, 30, 30);
self.proceedButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
self.proceedButton.titleLabel.text = @"button!!!!";
[self.proceedButton addTarget:self action:@selector(onAcceptClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
self.proceedButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[self.view addSubview:self.proceedButton];
```

**Test**

```
-(void)testButton {
    self.myVC = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyVC"];
    XCTAssertNotNil(self.myVC.view);
    NSString *selector = [[self.myVC.proceedButton actionsForTarget:self.myVC forControlEvent:UIControlEventTouchUpInside] firstObject];
    XCTAssert([selector isEqualToString:@"onAcceptClicked"]);
    [self.myVC.proceedButton sendActionsForControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
```

Comment: that didnt change anything in the actual app button works perfectly, but ` [vc.proceedButton sendActionsForControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];` seems like not doing anything

Comment: Did you try using the example code that I supplied? How are you actually `init`ing your button?

Comment: The view controller is created programmatically, looks like that is the only difference between my and your code

Comment: `self.proceedButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];`
  `[self.proceedButton setTitle:self.proceedButtonText forState:UIControlStateNormal];` looks like button init and add is get called thru breakpoints

Comment: Does it work if you replace your button creation code with mine?